# Vector of pointers, elements of which initialized with new: what happens when assigning a new value?

Tags: c++

I have a vector of pointers like this:

```
std::vector<foo*> stuff;
```

I initialize each element with a `new foo();`:

My question is what happens when I reassign one of the vector's elements, say

```
stuff[3] = new foo();
```

Am I leaking memory and should I have called `delete[]` before this? Is this a case where I should be using smart pointers? (never have so far)

Normally I would not be using new but I 'm learning Qt and this is how it seems done in the examples. Qt seems to have smart pointers of its own; should I be using one of those?

Thanks.

Comment: `new foo()` might lead to confusion (as on the stack you default-initialise without the parentheses) and you only use `delete[]` when you have allocated using `new[]`.

Comment: None of the answers was satisfactory so I provided what I gathered. Not sure who removed the Qt tag either, because the question had everything to do with Qt.
Normally in c++ I don't use `new` and `delete` at all, it's Qt that uses `new` liberally which led me to this question. Qt has its own parent/children system that takes cares of deletion and noone here pointed that out.

Comment: Well, you didn't specify that `foo` is derived from `QObject`, that's why the Qt tag was removed and that's also why no-one gave you the answer you where looking for. In general, the answers posted here where indeed answering your question, your answer is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `foo` are QObjects then assign to each a parent (which will be responsible for deleting them - although they could be deleted manually too). And in that case, do *not* use smart pointers as that will create ownership conflicts.

Comment: This isn't really an answer.

Comment: Edited. This is what I 've gathered, feel free to point out if I 'm missed something.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you leak when `stuff` get destructed leaving all those dynamic allocated `foo` undeleted and unreachable unless you iterate through the vector and call delete.

typically when you want a vector of pointer you use `std::shared_ptr`

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<foo>> stuff;

stuff[3] = std::make_shared<foo>();
```

this could potentially be a performance bottleneck if the vector is huge and you try to copy it( then perhaps you want to wrap it in another shared_ptr ), but if you are only accessing the element of the vector it eliminate all the problems about who delete what and when that come with the raw pointer approach.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is what happens when I reassign one of the vector's elements, say
>
> ```
> stuff[3] = new foo();
> ```
>
> Am I leaking memory

Yes, you're leaking memory.  The vector doesn't know who's responsible for owning the object you allocated.  It's can't tell the difference between:

```
stuff[3] = new foo();
```

and

```
foo f;
stuff[3] = &f;
```

Therefore it will not any cleanup for you.

> and should I have called `delete[]` before this?

Not quite. `delete[]` is used to destroy a dynamically allocated *array*; it's what you would use to destroy something allocated via `new[]`.  To destroy something allocated via plain `new`, you should use plain `delete`.

> Is this a case where I should be using smart pointers? (never have so far)

Yes.  If you used `std::shared_ptr<foo>` (or `boost::shared_ptr<foo>` if you can't use C++11), then the `std::shared_ptr` object would take responsibility for `delete`ing the object for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any relation with Qt in your code. memory leak occurs when don't call delete after you allocated the object with new. what you should do it to run a loop on that vector and call delete on each item.

Answer (score 0):

a vector makes a copy of the object and stores the copy. Now in your example, the vector is of the type `foo*`. So when it is passed a pointer to `foo`, vector makes a copy of the pointer, not the `foo` itself. Now when you reassign and do other stuff, the copy of the pointer is freed by vector, but not the memory pointed by the pointer. Imagine you have a vector of keys, so  the vector makes a copy of key passed to it, and frees the copy of the key. But it never touches the lock for which the key is. That you need to handle yourself. You can get the value and free the element yourself before reassigning.